# multiple queries on multiple indices and different rules in elastalert

Tags: elastalert

I want to run multiple queries on multiple indices of elasticsearch in elastalert. How can I do that?
for example : I want to use the first filter and type "any" on index abc*, the second filter and type "frequency" on index xyz*

```
 type: any
 type: frequency
 index: abc*
 index: xyz*
 filter:
  - match:
    loglevel: "INFO"
 filter:
  - match:
    loglevel: "ERROR"
```

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html

Comment: Thanks, it didn't give me any error, I need both the queries to work but only the second query is working.